# Magento backend create order missing "add product" button

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

I am using magento 2.4.2.
If i want to create a new order(sales -> orders -> create new order) than i am missing the "add product" button.

Like this.
https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047481431-Magento-2-4-0-known-issue-Create-New-Order-buttons-missing

We already tried the workaround. Only it didn't work.
There aren't any console.log error's

Comment: Have you provided the correct URL? You use version 2.4.2. and the URL is related to 2.4.0.

Comment: And from the page "A fix will be available in Magento 2.4.1."

Comment: Yes,
Is indeed for 2.4.0 but i have the issue on 2.4.2